wp_insert_term how to insert "<" or ">" in description
so i'm trying to insert an image to wp_insert_term() by
$args = array ( 'description' => '<img src="src">');
wp_insert_term( 'sample', 'taxonomy', $args ) ;

However it is being filtered even if I input only "<" or ">" it is not being entered into the description.
anyway to allow the character?

got the answer
foreach ( array( 'pre_term_description' ) as $filter ) {
    remove_filter( $filter, 'wp_filter_kses' );
}
foreach ( array( 'term_description' ) as $filter ) {
remove_filter( $filter, 'wp_kses_data' );
}

